# Downside of using non-ASCII language as source-code in django i18n?

Tags: python, django, localization, internationalization

Is there any downside, in terms of performance or difficulty, to use non-ASCII language as the source-language during an i18n?

Specifically, will it be equal, performance-wise, to have:

```
_("这是一条中文信息")
```

translated by from Chinese to English rather than:

```
_("this is an English message")
```

translated by from English to Chinese?

Comment: If you are on Python 3, your source code could likely already be utf8. An interesting question: how does the language affect the memory requirements of the source code?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So you mean there is no difference really?

Comment: No, there isn't any difference.

Comment: There will be a small performance cost. Chinese strings will take 2 bytes per character in memory, 3 on disk (or 4 and 4, if you use any characters behind the basic CJK set) instead of 1, meaning it will take a bit longer to read them, hash them, etc. I doubt it will make any noticeable difference in your overall performance (l10n is rarely a bottleneck), but if you want to be sure, take a piece of your code and `timeit` it both ways.

Comment: Also, a lot of older tools expect the untranslated strings to be ASCII or Latin-1, so you may not be able to use those tools, but I doubt you were planning to use any of them anyway. (AFAIK, it’s only people sticking with small commercial translation products who have that problem.) And if you were going to use a translation service, they generally deliver files in English->Chinese format, so you may have to write a 10-line script to convert them. But otherwise, I don’t think there’s any issue with difficulty of use.

Comment: @abarnert Thank you for your advice. I was thinking, provided a Eng-> Chn .po file, if only there exists some kind of magic, like the 10-line code you said, to actually loop through the django files and replace the {% trans '中文' %} tags to {% 'english' %} tags, hahaha :) . Before I started the project I had no idea that the process of i18n exists. I thought I had to provide 2 set of templates... I'm a cave man...